# VB.NET sorting string containing a name and a date,sorting it on the date of the string

Tags: vb.net, sorting, date

Hi i have thousands of transactions in my database which are having a transaction key mapped to them.
Now,what i do is that in my application i have a hashtable where in i store each of my transaction mapped to one transaction key.
so the hash table lets say for example looks like this

```
 MYHASH(key-->transactionkey,value--->transaction object)
```

The problem here is that my transaction key is made like this

```
 transaction key=transaction type+date
```

where the transaction type can be either "actual" or "manual"
after all these is done i store all these transaction keys in an array and then i call the Arrays.sort method.

The problem is that Arrays.sort sorts it alphabetically so Actual comes first and then manual,what i need here is that it should sort the keys on dates instead of the transaction type.

I can not change the way the transaction key is made because that will require changes everywhere in my program where ever i have used transaction keys.

Can some one please suggest something that can be done while sorting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim arr = New String() {"Actual2014/6/21", "Manual2014/5/12"}

arr = (From a In arr _
       Let datepos = a.LastIndexOf("/"c, a.LastIndexOf("/"c) - 1) - 4 _
       Order By _
         DateTime.Parse(Right(a, datepos)), _
         Left(a, datepos - 1) _
       Select a).ToArray()
```

---

To avoid allocating a new array, define a sorting function separately and use it:

```
Private Function CompareStupidKeys(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer
    Dim datepos_x = x.LastIndexOf("/"c, x.LastIndexOf("/"c) - 1) - 4
    Dim datepos_y = y.LastIndexOf("/"c, y.LastIndexOf("/"c) - 1) - 4

    Dim date_comparison = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(Right(x, datepos_x)), DateTime.Parse(Right(y, datepos_y)))
    If date_comparison = 0 Then
        Return String.Compare(Left(x, datepos_x - 1), Left(y, datepos_y - 1))
    Else
        Return date_comparison
    End If
End Function

....

Array.Sort(arr, AddressOf CompareStupidKeys)
```

Comment: can u pls explain what your code does,i am relatively new to vb.net,so have no idea what arr_ means here.

Comment: `arr` means your array of transaction keys, which you said you had (and tried to feed to `Array.Sort`). `arr _` is that with the [line continuation symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa711641(v=vs.71).aspx). If you have VB.NET that is new enough, you can omit the continuation symbols.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,your code worked perfectly for me with minor changes in it.

Comment: This works great, but what about if you are sorting records in the same list / array where some have date, some have date and time, and some don't have either (just strings)?

Comment: @thecoolmacdude Dates that don't have time in fact have midnight of the day as the time. Then you decide how those that don't have a date should compare to those that do, and reflect these changes in `CompareStupidKeys`, or in the linq query, e.g. `Order By HasDate(...), DateTime.Parse(...)`.